# Tengo que firmar digitalmente un documento XML con la librería xmlseclibs en Codeigniter4

Tags: php

Uso el ejemplo básico de **Github**, lo instalamos vía composer como se aconseja. El primer error lo tengo cuando quiere usar los archivos de la librería.

```
use RobRichards\XMLSecLibs\XMLSecurityDSig;
use RobRichards\XMLSecLibs\XMLSecurityKey;
```

eso ya no funciona, uso un acceso absoluto

```
require "../xmlseclibs/vendor/robrichards/xmlseclibs/src/XMLSecurityDSig.php";
require "../xmlseclibs/vendor/robrichards/xmlseclibs/src/XMLSecurityKey.php";
```

el error desaparece pero no reconoce la instancia

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
Class 'App\Controllers\DOMDocument' not found
```

No sé si estoy accediendo mal a los archivos, por eso no puedo instanciar el documento o hay otro error.

Answer (score 0):

Soluciones el problema declarando el uso de los archivos luego de la declaración del espacio de nombres en Codeigniter 4

```
namespace App\Controllers;

use RobRichards\XMLSecLibs\XMLSecurityDSig;
use RobRichards\XMLSecLibs\XMLSecurityKey;
use DOMDocument;
```

Saludos